# Java RMI MVC Pattern

Tags: java, model-view-controller, rmi

I am new to Java RMI and I am asked to work on a online trading website.For MVC design Pattern to be implemented in java rmi. I know that View goes in Client Side, Model goes in Server side but I am confused where will the controller go?

Answer (score 0):

please refer below diagram for mvc architecture [image: working of mvc model]

now for RMI. you need to create one interface which is both side (client and server side). because the bahaviour should be same.

further code for RMI connection you will get it from google :)

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick reply. So if i have to create a login page using MVC pattern then View will go to the Client side and Model will go to the Server side. but where will controller go? will it go to the server side as well?

Comment: look into link:    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16447443/client-mvc-vs-server-mvc